# HTML value as input for Javascript Function and Return the Output back to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

I`ve been trying to create a function that (1) uses data input from the HTML to make the calculation and (2) return the result back to the HTML.

I am having some trouble finding the mistake, if you could please help me I'd be glad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Celcius to Fahrenheit</h2>

    <input type="number" id="input-temperature"></input>
    <p id="calc-result"></p>

<script>
function toCelsius() {
    var x = document.getElementbyId("input-temperature").value;
    return (5/9) * (x-32);  
}
document.getElementById("calc-result").innerHTML = ("The result is" + toCelsius()); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your errors... you have a typo `getElementbyId()` which should be `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `getElementbyId`. It should be `getElementById` (capital `B`).

To calculate and display celcius, you can create a button and on click of the button call `toCelcius` function (as below).

I have made the following changes in the function:

1. Checking whether the value entered is blank using `if (x != "")`.

```js
function toCelsius() {
 var x = document.getElementById("input-temperature").value;
 var Celcius = 0;

 if ( x != "") Celcius = (5 / 9) * (x - 32);

 document.getElementById("calc-result").innerHTML = ("The result is " + Celcius);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input-temperature"></input>
<p id="calc-result"></p>
<button id="btnCalculate" onclick="toCelsius()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made some minor mistakes:

- getElementById instead of getElementbyId
- You'll need to update the value every time the input field changes: addEventListener('keyup', function() {...})
- You have the calculation in reverse: 9 / 5 * x + 32

This is my complete code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("input-temperature").addEventListener('keyup', onInputChanged);
})

function toCelsius() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input-temperature").value;
  return 9 / 5 * x + 32;  
}

function onInputChanged() {
  document.getElementById("calc-result").innerHTML = "The result is " + toCelsius(); 
}
```

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/bertyhell/pen/WZQQgZ?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks a lot! I havent learned EventListener yet but since you mentioned it I believe now would be a great time to find out more about it. Thanks again!